# Safari — Cannot create Oscillator after the first few

Tags: javascript, safari, es6-promise, web-audio-api

I am trying to work with the WebAudio API, but have a problem getting it to work properly with Safari. My experiment works properly with Firefox and Chrome.

I have written a Promisified function to play a single note, and then try to play a series of notes using that function.

On Safari only, it fails after the first four notes with the following message:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'context.createOscillator')

OK, I haven’t handled the error, but why am I getting it? It suggests a limit of four oscillators.

```js
function tone(frequency,duration) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
  var audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var context=new audioContext;
  var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
  oscillator.connect(context.destination);
  oscillator.type='sawtooth';
  oscillator.start(context.currentTime);
  oscillator.stop(context.currentTime+duration);
  oscillator.onended=resolve;
 });
}
document.querySelector('button#play-test').onclick=function(event) {
 tone(130.81,1)
 .then(()=>tone(146.83,1))
 .then(()=>tone(164.81,1))
 .then(()=>tone(174.61,1))
 .then(()=>tone(196.00,1))
 ;
};
```

```html
<button id="play-test">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is in the number of AudioContexts you can run simultaneously.

Some browsers have such a limit, because an AudioContext requires resources from the Hardware (sound card) and that this Hardware has limits.

So refactor your code so that it doesn't create a new AudioContext every times:

```js
// create a single audio context
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function tone(frequency, duration) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
    oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
    oscillator.connect(context.destination);
    oscillator.type = 'sawtooth';
    oscillator.start(context.currentTime);
    oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + duration);
    oscillator.onended = resolve;
  });
}
document.querySelector('button#play-test').onclick = function(event) {
  tone(130.81, 1)
    .then(() => tone(146.83, 1))
    .then(() => tone(164.81, 1))
    .then(() => tone(174.61, 1))
    .then(() => tone(196.00, 1))
    .catch(console.error);
};
```

```html
<button id="play-test">Play</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked perfectly. I though that the context was disposed of automatically. What happens to the `oscillator` object?

Comment: It should indeed get disposed of in your code after the oscillator ends, but that may only happen when the GarbageCollector will kick in, which in normal cases should not be very often. Your oscillator has like no weight and also just dies after its onend event. For AudioContext: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#lifetime-AudioContext and for AudioNode: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioNode-actively-processing